# How to execute WSL command with preloaded ".bash_aliases" from powershell

Tags: bash, powershell, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to run WSL commands from CMD/PS, without actually entering the the WSL shell, eg:
`wsl -d myDistro -u myUser echo $MY_EXP_VAR`
I have my variables and aliases defined in `~/.bash_aliases` (they were also in `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, and when I open the WSL shell, just by `wsl [enter]` or with those params, all the aliases and exported vars are available for me, but when I try to run the as show before `wsl -d myDistro -u myUser echo $MY_EXP_VAR` it prints empty line, when I run `wsl -d myDistro -u myUser cat ~/.bash_aliases` it prints the file correctly.
I already tried to add

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

at the end of `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` but this didn't help.
Any hints how to add my vars so I can execute commands without starting the shell? I need this to run commands from AndroidStudio as a run config, not from terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On mobile at the moment, so I haven't had a chance to double check this, but from memory ...

Try:

```
wsl -d myDistro -u myUser -e bash -li -c 'echo $MY_EXP_VAR'
```

That should allow your profile to execute since you are running bash as a login shell and asking it to source the interactive startup scripts as well. If you don't force the `-li`, WSL runs Bash non-interactively and as a non-login shell, which explains why your config doesn't get sourced.

Comment: this is strange... when I run: ```wsl -d distro -u myUser -e bash -li -c "echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT"``` it prints empty line, but then ```wsl -d distro -u myUser -e bash -li -c "./gradlew tasks"``` runs fine, when it normally need the exported var, or config in project for the SDK...

Comment: Still away from computer, but maybe single quotes? It may be  that the `$` is being gobbled by PowerShell before it gets to bash?

Comment: Excellent - Edited the answer with that fix